# Alarm repeat in particular time interval

Tags: iphone, ios, exception, uilocalnotification

I know this question ask several time. Even i am trying this below code:

http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.in/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html

Still I am not able to play alarm at particular time interval.
I have date-time picker. User select time from that date-time picker, which contain time from 1 min to 23 hours.

In my app alarm works but only one time. I need to play that alarm till user does not stop that timer switch from on to off.

Please Help me.
Any idea and suggestion is Appreciated!!!!

Comment: Are you using UILocalNotification? You can set the repeatInterval or repeatCalendar

Comment: yes, i am using UILocalNotification but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `RepeatInterval` for your `localNotification`

```
[localNotification setRepeatInterval:NSMinuteCalendarUnit];
```

you can set its repeat interval according to you, it would be minute, hours, day,month, year.

Comment: Thanks alot, it works.., but it works for only 1min not for more than one min.

Comment: you can schedule as hours , day etc